# how to predict for new data points using random sampled features with kernel regression

Tags: regression

in kernel regression with n samples and k features I know how to predict new data point once we have a n by n kernel matrix - assuming it is gaussian kernel. when n is too large my understanding is I can use RBF sampler to reduce to r dimension where I can choose r<<n. and then run a linear regression to calculate beta which is a vector of size r
my question is in the new sampled space, how do you make prediction with new data points where each data point is a vector of the original k features. do I need to use the r random variables drawn for sampling (each one is size k vector) and apply them to the new data points to transform the new data point with k original features into the new r dimension vector and then apply beta to predict the y?